# Find width by appending span to body

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working in jquery and javascript.Here is my problem.
I have want to find a pixel length of a string.
So what is did is

```
    var text = 'abc';
    $('body').append('<span id="string_span" style="font-weight: bold; font-size: 0.7em">' + text
 + '</span>');
    console.log("width of text is " + $('#string_span').width());
    $('#string_span').remove();
```

But the problem is that what ever is my text length it is always returning 49.
Can any one guide me where i am doing wrong

Also I get correct values of width when I append my span to some other div instead of body
thanks

Comment: No No I am sorry I made this mistake here.....corrected it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

variable name is text, not 'abc'. **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/3rr8G/)**

```
var text = 'absadfc';
$('body').append('<span id="string_span" style="font-weight: bold; font-size: 0.7em">' + text + '</span>');
    console.log("width of text is " + $('#string_span').width());
$('#string_span').remove();
```

Comment: See you code, do you have any CSS for `span` or `#string_span` ?

Comment: No. String span is only created here there is no css for it

Comment: When I append th string_span to some other div it works fine....but not working on appending span with the body

Comment: Yeah I have created the same.. and its working .........So some other part of my code is affecting this...... :/

Comment: THe only difference i see is that I am passing the text as argument